# get comments and get posts in loop

Tags: posts, loop, comments, get-posts

I need to get posts done by specific users and get also comments done to these posts, so far I can get the posts and comments but can't get how to do it in loop properly, because now I get the same comments displayed for each post no matter to which posts they actually belong to...

So here is the code...loop inside another one, I am now quite sure that is the way it should...

So the output in my case: list of posts + each posts get ALL the comments which have ever been done...

I want to get post + only its comments in a loop
(I will put only php)

```
        <?php $posts = get_recent_posts_by_author_role('tenant');
                        foreach($posts as $post) {
                            $title=$post->post_title;
                            $perma_link=get_permalink($post->ID);
                            $img_post=get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
                            $author_name=$post->post_author;
                            $content_post=$post->post_content;
                            $date=$post->post_date;
                            $content_style="comment_text"; 

                        ?>

<?php $comment=get_comments($post->ID);
                                foreach($comment as $com){

                                    $com_author=$com->comment_author;
                                    $com_date=$com->comment_date;
                                    $com_content=$com->comment_content;
                                    global $authordata;
                                    $author_roles=$authordata->roles;
                                    ?>

<?php  }?>
<?php  }?>
```

Comment: You want to attach the same comments to ***each and every*** post? Why not simply hard code them then? Btw, `<?php ?>` is no line break. Use it _before_ starting PHP code and close it afterwards `?>` again.

Comment: How to get authors profile image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`get_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) accepts an array of arguments, you are passing an integer.

If you want to retrieve all comments for a post use:

```
get_comments( array('post_id' => $post->ID, 'status' => 'approve') );
```

To get an already formatted comment list, is easier use the [`wp_list_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) function, instead of another foreach cycle (code from codex):

```
  echo '<ol class="commentlist">';
  //Gather comments for a specific page/post 
  $comments = get_comments(array(
    'post_id' => $post->ID,
     'status' => 'approve'
  ));
  wp_list_comments(array(
    'per_page' => 10, // Allow comment pagination
     'reverse_top_level' => false //Show the latest comments at the top of the list
   ), $comments);
  echo '</ol>';
```

Answer (score 0):

get_comments accepts an array of arguments, you are passing an integer.

If you want to retrieve all comments for a post use:

```
get_comments( array('post_id' => $post->ID, 'status' => 'approve') );
To get an already formatted comment list, is easier use the wp_list_comments() function, instead of another foreach cycle (code from codex):

  echo '<ol class="commentlist">';
  //Gather comments for a specific page/post 
  $comments = get_comments(array(
    'post_id' => $post->ID,
     'status' => 'approve'
  ));
  wp_list_comments(array(
    'per_page' => 10, // Allow comment pagination
     'reverse_top_level' => false //Show the latest comments at the top of the list
   ), $comments);
  echo '</ol>';
```